# Is there any way to make my form not close after submitting and false the validator

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a database called 'shop' which have a table named 'shop'. 'a.php' will fetch data of products and show in a table. When click on button 'Create new product', it will load a form from 'b.php' . 'b.php' include "validate.php" ,which is used to validate inputs and change the database. However, after submitting, even when the validator is false, the form will close instead of staying still and displaying validate_error_message. How can i fix this problem? Sorry about my English.

a.php

```
<div class="main">
           
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="getForm('create',0)">Create New Product</button>
            <!-- begin: product table -->
            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm mt-2">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                foreach ($products as $product){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $product['id']          ?></th>
                        <td ><?php echo $product['name']        ?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $product['description'] ?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $product['price']       ?></td>
                        <td class= "d-flex">
                            
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ms-1" onclick="getForm('edit',<?php echo $product['id']; ?>)">Edit  </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ms-2"  onclick="getForm('delete',<?php echo $product['id']; ?>)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
            </table>
            <!-- end: product table -->
            
            <!-- begin: form -->
            <div id="productForm">

            </div>
            <!-- end: form -->
            <script>
                function getForm(str,num) {
                    var xhttp;    
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("productForm").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        }
                    };
                    switch(str){
                        case "create":
                            xhttp.open("GET", "b.php", true);
                            break;
                        case "edit":
                            xhttp.open("GET", "c.php?id="+num, true);
                            break;
                        case "delete":
                            xhttp.open("GET", "d.php?id="+num, true);
                            // console.log('delete');
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    xhttp.send();
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

b.php

```
<?php
    require_once "db.php";
    $validate_name_message = $validate_desc_message  = "";
    $validate_img_message  = $validate_price_message = "";
    $validate_success_message="";   
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['formAction']='create';
    require "validate.php";
?>
<!-- begin: create new product form -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header header class="header">
        <h3>Create new product</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="main">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter product name"> 
                <?php echo $validate_name_message ?><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="desc">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Enter product description">
                <?php echo $validate_desc_message ?><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Enter product price">
                <?php echo $validate_price_message ?><br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="img">Image</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="img" placeholder="Enter product's link">
                <?php echo $validate_img_message ?><br>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            
            <?php echo $validate_success_message ?><br>
            
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end: create new product form -->
```

validate.php

```
<?php 
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $flag=0;
        // validate name
        if(empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $validate_name_message = "<span style='color:red;'>This field must be fill out!</span>";
            $flag++;
        }
        else{
            $name = $_POST["name"];
            if(strlen($name)<5||strlen($name)>40){
            $validate_firstName_message = "<span style='color:red;'>Name must includes 5-40 characters!</span>";
            $flag++;
            }
            
        }
        // validate description
        if(empty($_POST["desc"])) {
            $validate_desc_message = "<span style='color:red;'>This field must be fill out!</span>";
            $flag++;
        }
        else{
            $desc = $_POST["desc"];
            if(strlen($desc)>5000){
            $validate_desc_message = "<span style='color:red;'>Description must not exceed 5000 characters!</span>";
            $flag++;
            }
        }
        // validate price
        if(empty($_POST["price"])) {
            $validate_price_message = "<span style='color:red;'>This field must be fill out!</span>";
            $flag++;
        }
        else {
            $price = $_POST["price"];
            if (!is_numeric($price)){
                $validate_price_message = "<span style='color:red;'>Price must be a number</span>";
                $flag++;
            }
        }
        //validate image
        if(empty($_POST["img"])) {
            $validate_img_message = "<span style='color:red;'>This field must be fill out!</span>";
            $flag++;
        }
        else {
            $img = $_POST["img"];
            if (strlen($img)>255){
                $validate_img_message = "<span style='color:red;'>Image link must not exceed 255 characters!</span>";
                $flag++;
            }
        }

        // if there is zero wrong input on submit action
        if($flag<=0){
            //add new product to database
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $desc = $_POST['desc'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            $img = $_POST['img'];
            if($_SESSION['formAction']=='create'){
                
                $q = "INSERT INTO `products` (`name`,`description`,`price`,`image`) 
                    VALUES ('$name','$desc','$price','$img') ";
            }
            else if($_SESSION['formAction']=='edit'){
                $productID = $_SESSION['id'];
                
                $q = "UPDATE products 
                      SET name='$name',description='$desc',price='$price',image='$img'
                      WHERE id = $productID";
            }
            $query = mysqli_query($con,$q);
            session_destroy();
            //print success message
            $validate_success_message = "<span style='color:red;'>Success!</span>";
            header('Location: a.php');
        }
        else {
            
            //print fail message
            $validate_success_message = "<span style='color:red;'>Fail!</span>";
        }
        
    }
    
?>
```

I expect that after submiting form, if there is no wrong input, the form will close and the table will update without reloading. If the validator is false, the form will not close and display validate_error_message

Comment: No one can go through so much code which cant we reproduce here on StackOverflow. So edit your code, and post where you are stuck.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).